# OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster - Photon (Unity 3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

JoinOrCreateRoom failed. Client is on GameServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking) and
ready. Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP5oO.png)

> 

.
Please help us out with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have already joined in a room.
To change the room, before you have to leave that with `PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom()` and in the method `OnConnectedToMaster()` call `PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom(…)`

Good work!